# Dynamically populating an object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, c#-4.0

I have an excel sheet with cells . I want to read and populate an object at runtime.
This is what I tried.

```
dynamic Common = new JObject();

foreach (DataRow dsRow in dtTable.Rows)
{
    // On all tables' columns
    foreach(DataColumn dc in dtTable.Columns)
    {

    var columnName = dc.ColumnName;
        Common.columnName = dsRow[dc].ToString();
    }
}
```

But the problem here is  `dtoCommonTag.columnName` is constant for all the columns from `dsRow[dc].ToString()`.

How do I dynamically change the **key** values of **Common**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options here:

Have you tried

```
Common[columnName] = dsRow[dc].ToString();
```

Worst case scenario, you can write a switch statement to affect every column. It won't be pretty but it will work.

Comment: What's the second option?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar It's right there in the answer: "write a switch statement to affect every column".

Answer (score 1):

That is not how `dynamic` objects work. You can dynamically add properties to a dynamic object, but not "by string".

You can, however, use an `ExpandoObject` to do that:

```
var x = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
x.Add(columnName, dsRow[dc].ToString());

dynamic dyn = x;
```

Then you can use the column names as properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Reflection".
Then you can pass the property name as a string value and then pass a value to that property.
[Try this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/reflection)

```
FieldInfo info = typeof(Common).GetField(dc.ColumnName);
info.SetValue(null, dsRow[dc].ToString())
```